# DNS setup for Office 365

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365

I am trying to add a dns verification record for Office 365 without success. The help says that I need to create a TXT record in my domain with the following properties:

Alias or Host Name: @
Destination or Points to Address: MS=ms79951xxx
TTL: 1 Hour

We use Windows Server 2008 as our dns server. I couldn't find how to add this record.

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok I added the record without specifying "@" as the host name. Now I can successfully query the txt record with nslookup but Office 365 still doesn't verify. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it didn't propagate yet. - caching DNS servers could cache negative result from previous lookups (the fact that there's NO such records). If it's the case, you'll have to wait until cache expires.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to follow the steps in this support article from Microsoft: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/gg584188.aspx#BKMK_gather?

As I read it, these changes must be made in public DNS, it sounds like you are trying to add the TXT record to your local Microsoft DNS server. Try adding this record to your public DNS service instead

Comment: Our DNS server is open to public and it runs on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: What domain you are trying to verify and what is the fqdn of your DNS server?